# JavaScript replace function with global set not working for firefox version 14

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, replacewith

I am using replace function to replace profile path of a user globally.

The `user.profile_path` has value like `http://mysite/user/profile/XXXXXX`

The code looks like:

```
.replace(/{:profile_path}/g,user.profile_path)
```

It is working fine in IE and chrome and latest Firefox browsers.But when i tried the same in Firefox version 14, the replace is not working. I searched and found that giving "g" for replace is not web standard as not all browsers support this. Then i tried giving Regular Expression for same like:

```
var regProfPath = new RegExp("{:profile_path}","g");
.replace(regProfPath,user.profile_path)
```

This also didn't replace the profile path globally.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you just wanting to overwrite the `http://mysite/user/profile/XXXXXX` with `{:profile_path}`?

Comment: yes i have few places in my html where i want to replace {:profile_path} with correct profile path.

Comment: actually the same works ok for name as i have given title for name container and its having pattern like {:display_name} and is replaced correctly twice... only {:profile_path} pattern is not replaced and i hv no clue as both use same logic.

Comment: I think you'll want to escape the curly braces `\{:profile_path\}`

Comment: sorry where did you mention to escape? in first option ie, replace(/{:profile_path}/g,user.profile_path) or in new RegExp()??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how *globally* you want to replace this; but assuming for a moment that your HTML content on the page where you want to replace this is in a `DIV` with class `.content`, you could use:

```
var user = {},
    content = $('.content').html();

user.profile_path = "http:\/\/mysite\/user\/profile\/XXXXXX";

$('.content').html(content.replace(/\{\:profile_path\}/gm, user.profile_path));
```

Tested specifically in FF 14 and it worked.  Looks like it was likely the escaping of the `}`s . Even though I added the `m` (multiline) modifier, I don't think that has an effect; just put it in since I figured you were probably dealing with a large, multiline string if you were replacing globally across stringified HTML.